# Unable to read the html file using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization

I am unable to read the HTML files using pandas. Below is the error screenshot:

[image]

Comment: whats the `html5lib` version?

Comment: the html5lib version is '0.999999999'

Comment: upgrade your `pandas` then try again

Comment: upgraded pandas, but still receving the same error

Comment: can't reproduce this in python3 with following versions, `pandas '0.20.3'`, `bs4 '4.6.0'`, and `html5lib '0.999999999'`. it loads it up for me.

Comment: facing this error for python3

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer to the link for the same html parsing problem discussed in stackoverflow: 
[html5lib: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086278/html5lib-typeerror-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-encoding)

You have to install via pip

> html5lib=="0.9999999"

The problem here persists with the html5lib parse tree so you have to install html5lib separately since we can't upgrade specific modules in Pandas library.