# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Attempting a scrape of table data using pandas in Python 3.6 using Spyder3 on a MacBook Pro OS v10.13.2 (17C88). The code is:

```
import pandas as pd
...

url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/?start=20130428&end="+time.strftime("%Y%m%d")

# CODE FAILS HERE
bitcoin_market_info = pd.read_html(url)[0]
```

The results shown in the console:

```
bitcoin_market_info = pd.read_html(url)[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-0b0d269a2c9d>", line 15, in <module>
    bitcoin_market_info = pd.read_html(url)[0]

  File "/Users/EL-C/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 915, in read_html
    keep_default_na=keep_default_na)

  File "/Users/EL-C/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 749, in _parse
    raise_with_traceback(retained)

  File "/Users/EL-C/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 385, in raise_with_traceback
    raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'
```

pd.**version** is '0.21.1'

Results of pd.show_versions():

```
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 3.6.4.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Darwin
OS-release: 17.3.0
machine: x86_64
processor: i386
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: en_US.UTF-8
LANG: en_US.UTF-8
LOCALE: en_US.UTF-8

pandas: 0.21.1
pytest: 3.3.0
pip: 9.0.1
setuptools: 36.5.0.post20170921
Cython: 0.27.3
numpy: 1.13.3
scipy: 1.0.0
pyarrow: None
xarray: None
IPython: 6.2.1
sphinx: 1.6.3
patsy: 0.4.1
dateutil: 2.6.1
pytz: 2017.3
blosc: None
bottleneck: 1.2.1
tables: 3.4.2
numexpr: 2.6.4
feather: None
matplotlib: 2.1.1
openpyxl: 2.4.9
xlrd: 1.1.0
xlwt: 1.2.0
xlsxwriter: 1.0.2
lxml: 4.1.1
bs4: 4.6.0
html5lib: 1.0.1
sqlalchemy: 1.1.13
pymysql: None
psycopg2: None
jinja2: 2.10
s3fs: None
fastparquet: None
pandas_gbq: None
pandas_datareader: None
```

I have attempted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45726184/unable-to-read-the-html-file-using-pandas?noredirect=1&lq=1) fix, but it seems to be for an older version and not exactly this situation, given that I haven't imported html5lib.

In case it's needed:

the html5lib.**version** is 1.0.1

bs4.**version** is 4.6.0

Running 'pip3 install -U html5lib=="0.9999999"' (as suggested) in the terminal doesn't change the version in Spyder3.

What I see in the terminal when running the command is:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: html5lib==0.9999999 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: six in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from html5lib==0.9999999)
```

Maybe this is the root? If so, need help figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install [Anaconda Python distributive (available for Linux, Windows and MacOS](https://www.anaconda.com/download/)

It works perfectly fine for me:

```
In [133]: bitcoin_market_info = pd.read_html(url)[0]

In [134]: bitcoin_market_info
Out[134]:
              Date      Open      High       Low     Close       Volume    Market Cap
0     Dec 26, 2017  14036.60  16461.20  14028.90  16099.80  13454300000  235294000000
1     Dec 25, 2017  13995.90  14593.00  13448.90  14026.60  10664700000  234590000000
2     Dec 24, 2017  14608.20  14626.00  12747.70  13925.80  11572300000  244824000000
3     Dec 23, 2017  13948.70  15603.20  13828.80  14699.20  13086000000  233748000000
4     Dec 22, 2017  15898.00  15943.40  11833.00  13831.80  22198000000  266381000000
5     Dec 21, 2017  16642.40  17567.70  15342.70  15802.90  16516600000  278827000000
6     Dec 20, 2017  17760.30  17934.70  16077.70  16624.60  22149700000  297526000000
7     Dec 19, 2017  19118.30  19177.80  17275.40  17776.70  16894500000  320242000000
8     Dec 18, 2017  19106.40  19371.00  18355.90  19114.20  14839500000  320000000000
9     Dec 17, 2017  19475.80  20089.00  18974.10  19140.80  13314600000  326141000000
...            ...       ...       ...       ...       ...          ...           ...
1694  May 07, 2013    112.25    113.44     97.70    111.50            -    1248470000
1695  May 06, 2013    115.98    124.66    106.64    112.30            -    1289470000
1696  May 05, 2013    112.90    118.80    107.14    115.91            -    1254760000
1697  May 04, 2013     98.10    115.00     92.50    112.50            -    1089890000
1698  May 03, 2013    106.25    108.13     79.10     97.75            -    1180070000
1699  May 02, 2013    116.38    125.60     92.28    105.21            -    1292190000
1700  May 01, 2013    139.00    139.89    107.72    116.99            -    1542820000
1701  Apr 30, 2013    144.00    146.93    134.05    139.00            -    1597780000
1702  Apr 29, 2013    134.44    147.49    134.00    144.54            -    1491160000
1703  Apr 28, 2013    135.30    135.98    132.10    134.21            -    1500520000

[1704 rows x 7 columns]
```

Module's Versions:

```
In [135]: pd.show_versions()

INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 3.6.3.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Windows
OS-release: 7
machine: AMD64
processor: Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: en_US.UTF-8
LANG: en_US
LOCALE: None.None

pandas: 0.21.1
pytest: 3.3.0
pip: 9.0.1
setuptools: 36.5.0.post20170921
Cython: 0.27.3
numpy: 1.13.3
scipy: 1.0.0
pyarrow: 0.7.0
xarray: 0.10.0
IPython: 6.2.1
sphinx: 1.6.3
patsy: 0.4.1
dateutil: 2.6.1
pytz: 2017.3
blosc: 1.5.1
bottleneck: 1.2.1
tables: 3.4.2
numexpr: 2.6.4
feather: 0.4.0
matplotlib: 2.1.1
openpyxl: 2.4.9
xlrd: 1.1.0
xlwt: 1.3.0
xlsxwriter: 1.0.2
lxml: 4.1.1
bs4: 4.6.0
html5lib: 1.0.1
sqlalchemy: 1.1.13
pymysql: 0.7.11.None
psycopg2: 2.7.3.1 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)
jinja2: 2.10
s3fs: None
fastparquet: None
pandas_gbq: None
pandas_datareader: 0.5.0
```

[read_html()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) uses lxml per default (`flavor=None`):

> **flavor** : str or None, container of strings
>
> The parsing engine to use. `bs4` and `html5lib` are synonymous with each other, they are
>
> both there for backwards compatibility. The default of `None` tries to
>
> use `lxml` to parse and if that fails it falls back on `bs4 + html5lib`.

Comment: Installed the Python distributive. Restarted. No success. I noticed that I don't have pandas_datareader installed. Would that have an effect?

Comment: @user, did you try to run it from Anaconda's ipython shell? I don't think you need pandas_datareader in this case...

Comment: Installed the distributive via a .pkg from the link you posted. The code is all run in .py files in Spyder3. Hope that answers it - wasn't sure which 'it' you're referring to re running in the ipython shell.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install -U html5lib=="0.9999999"
```

here's the [html5lib bug on github](https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-python/issues/281)

from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39087283