# pip throws TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transport_encoding' when trying to install new packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda

I am using the latest version of Anaconda3. I just installed it and I am trying to download some packages. I am using the Anaconda Prompt. While trying to use pip to do anything (including upgrading existing packages) I get the following traceback.

```
    Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\csprock\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\csprock\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "C:\Users\csprock\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "C:\Users\csprock\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Users\csprock\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 487, in _prepare_file
    req_to_install, finder)
  File "C:\Users\csprock\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 428, in _check_skip_installed
    req_to_install, upgrade_allowed)
  File "C:\Users\csprock\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "C:\Users\csprock\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "C:\Users\csprock\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "C:\Users\csprock\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "C:\Users\csprock\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 811, in get_page
    inst = cls(resp.content, resp.url, resp.headers)
  File "C:\Users\csprock\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 731, in __init__
    namespaceHTMLElements=False,
TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transport_encoding'
```

Any ideas? (this problem only started after I installed tensorflow) Thanks.

Comment: Got the same problem

Comment: Does `conda install` work?

Comment: Conda works but not all packages are supported.

Comment: Also, this problem only started after installing TensorFlow.

Comment: me too. win 10 and Anaconda 3

Comment: I can confirm it happened for me after installing Tensorflow on Anaconda 3 for Windows 10. Installed a bunch of plugins, then after Tensorflow couldn't install any more.

Answer (score 196):

I had the same problem and what worked for me was updating pip with conda:

`conda install pip`

It changed my pip from  9.0.1-py36hadba87b_3 to 9.0.1-py36h226ae91_4 and solved issue.

Comment: Worked for me too. Thank you. In my case Info was like this: The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel: pip: 9.0.1-py36hadba87b_3 --> 9.0.1-py36_0 conda-forge

Comment: I had the same problem, like the 6 above, this worked for me as well.

Comment: Mine is already on py35h691316f_4 and this command is not changing anything. I'm still getting the exception.

Comment: This worked for me:

python -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow

Comment: Awesome. It worked. The problem was with tensorflow and pip co-existence.

Comment: I was running into this same error with "pip install plyfile" and making no headway in separate SO q&a effort to resolve it.  This resolved that error for me as well and really appreciate you calling out the pip from and to version change that "conda install pip" applied as I just saw the same 9.0.1 version prefix and figured no update was going to happen.

Comment: Works for me! "Run as Administrator" if you are Windows user.

Comment: CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist.

Answer (score 29):

download https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-python/tree/master/html5lib and overwrite all the files within html5lib folder in your tensorflow environment 
"envs\tensorflow\Lib\site-packages\html5lib"
Then you should be able to run any "pip install" commands after that

Comment: Piggybacking on Romeo's answer, `conda install --force html5lib` fixed the problem for me.

Comment: tried this for both tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu and doesnt traceback error remains exactly the same: File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 731, in __init__
    namespaceHTMLElements=False,
TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transport_encoding

Comment: ok got it working. so its not the tensorflows install that you should replace but your anaconda3 html5lib -> \Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\html5lib   . this made it work for me finally.

Comment: @MikeLanzetta solution did not work for me. `conda install -c anaconda html5lib` worked

Answer (score 10):

I ran into the same problem while installing keras (after I installed tensorflow 1.3 using pip) on the latest version of Anaconda 3. I was able to fix the problem by installing keras using conda `conda install -c conda-forge keras`

Comment: This does not work for me, Win 10 Anaconda 5.0.0 python 3.6 tensorflow 1.3 cuda 8 and cudnn 6

Comment: Looks like you're installing the tensorflow gpu version, not sure that would work with Anaconda.

Comment: doesnt work for me either. on keras                     2.0.6                    py36_0    conda-forge

Answer (score 7):

I was getting this exact error installing SerpentAI. All I did to fix it was run `activate serpent` in conda prompt and then I ran the command again. Not sure if it's applicable to your situation, but they seem close enough that it might.

EDIT - if the above didn't work, comment out this line:
[image]

That worked perfectly for me.
(this took a helpful member of our community 8 hours to debug)

Comment: what is "activate"? I don't see that as a listed conda command.

Comment: it is to use a virtual environment created from [conda] (https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)

Comment: On manjaro linux, the file is located `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py` , commented same line. Now works prefectly

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

> python -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install -U html5lib=="0.9999999"
```

worked for me

here's the [html5lib bug on github](https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-python/issues/281)

from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39087283

Answer (score 0):

Here was the fix for me:

```
cd /usr/share/python-wheels/
```

Contents of dir:

```
-rwxrwxrwx   1 www-data www-data 493905 Jul 22  2015 html5lib-0.999-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root     112620 Apr  3  2019 html5lib-0.999999999-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

Run:

```
mv html5lib-0.999-py2.py3-none-any.whl html5lib-0.999-py2.py3-none-any.whl.bak
```

pip3 works fine after. Was loading the old 0.999 version.