# Tensorflow breaks pip on anaconda, windows os

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pip, anaconda

Last version of anaconda, windows 10, python 3.6.
Installing tensorflow seems to break pip.

```
>conda create -n py6 python=3.6
>activate py6
>conda install tensorflow
>pip install tweepy
Collecting tweepy
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\py6\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\py6\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "C:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\py6\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "C:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\py6\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\py6\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "C:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\py6\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "C:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\py6\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "C:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\py6\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "C:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\py6\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "C:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\py6\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "C:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\py6\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 811, in get_page
    inst = cls(resp.content, resp.url, resp.headers)
  File "C:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\py6\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 731, in __init__
    namespaceHTMLElements=False,
TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transport_encoding'
```

Use of tweepy is just an example, pip cannot install any package.

The same happens when installing tensorflow using pip, and when using a python 3.5 virtual environment.

Probably this is due to some package update gone wrong, and it will be fixed in the next update.
Meanwhile, any fix or any careful selection of working version numbers is welcome.

Comment: Other have [reported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46499808/pip-throws-typeerror-when-trying-to-install-packages#) this issue. I have posted a new question because I can' t comment on their question due to low rep, and also to explicitly mention tensorflow, which in the other question is mentioned as a marginal detail.

Comment: The tensorflow-gpu package works correctly, so it is a problem of the cpu-only package.

Comment: See the second solution of my answer here for the same problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46517130/7213753

Comment: tensorflow gpu same problem, breaks pip

Comment: same problem, still havnt been able to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issues is reported in the following ticket : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/588

To solve this, you need to repair html5lib. 
Or alternatively, 
you can make use of anaconda to re-install

```
conda install -c anaconda html5lib
```

Comment: This did not work for me. I am still getting the same exception after running it.

Comment: Can you try on removing the html5lib first ?
`conda remove html5lib`
Then you install it again

`conda install -c anaconda html5lib`

Comment: I have no idea why but this worked for me and now I can use tensorflow:

`python -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow`

Comment: From what i understand form the ticket that i posted here. Tensorflow seems overrided html5lib version, and yet causing this error been see in pip. However, we should not observe any problem in tensorflow. It is only causing issues in pip. Hopefully i am answering your question.