# Issues with pip install after installing Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I have `Anaconda 5.0`, `Windows 10`.

I have installed `Tensorflow` with `pip install tensorflow` in the Anaconda Prompt.

Installation was successful. The test suggested on the [website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) worked as expected.

But now I cannot install any other package with `pip install`. For instance when I run:

`pip install memory-profiler` I get:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 811, in get_page
    inst = cls(resp.content, resp.url, resp.headers)
  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 731, in __init__
    namespaceHTMLElements=False,
TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transport_encoding'
```

How can I remedy this?

---

The problem persists after running:

`conda upgrade pip`

Also, the solution provided by Romeo, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46499808/pip-throws-typeerror-parse-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-transport-enco), does not work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip throws TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transport\_encoding' when trying to install new packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46499808/pip-throws-typeerror-parse-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-transport-enco)

Answer (score 1):

Solved by running:

`conda install --force html5lib`

(credit: Mike Lanzetta)