# Installing fancyimpute using pip command

Tags: python, scikit-learn, fancyimpute

Updating pip with conda worked in installing fancyimpute But now I am getting import error,i have insatlled tensorflow using pip:from fancyimpute import KNN
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py__init__.py:34: FutureWarning: C
onversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is
deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`
.

```
 from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tens
orflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [
dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tens
    orflow.py", line 58, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tens
    orflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
        _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tens
    orflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
        import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "fancy.py", line 1, in <module>
            from fancyimpute import MICE
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fancyimpute\__init__.py", lin
        e 7, in <module>
            from .matrix_factorization import MatrixFactorization
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fancyimpute\matrix_factorizat
        ion.py", line 16, in <module>
            from keras import regularizers
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, i
        n <module>
            from . import utils
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", lin
        e 6, in <module>
            from . import conv_utils
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", l
        ine 9, in <module>
            from .. import backend as K
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", l
        ine 83, in <module>
            from .tensorflow_backend import *
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_back
        end.py", line 5, in <module>
            import tensorflow as tf
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line
         24, in <module>
            from tensorflow.python import *
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py
        ", line 49, in <module>
            from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
          File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tens
        orflow.py", line 72, in <module>
            raise ImportError(msg)
        ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):

              File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tens
            orflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
                fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [
            dirname(__file__)])
              File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
                raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
            ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

            During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tens
            orflow.py", line 58, in <module>
                from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
              File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tens
            orflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
                _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
              File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tens
            orflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
                import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
            ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


            Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

        See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_probl
        ems

        for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
        above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip throws TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transport\_encoding' when trying to install new packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46499808/pip-throws-typeerror-parse-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-transport-enco)

Comment: It worked but I  am gettinthis error when import from fancyimpute:  
 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py:34: FutureWarning: C
onversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is
deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type
`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Using TensorFlow backend.

Comment: That's not an error, that's a warning like it says (and a lot of information is contained!). And don't spam that stuff into comments, edit the question (to make use of formatting-tools).

Comment: But I am not able to import from fancyimpute....I am getting a huge set of tensorflow error..

Comment: Then you are omitting information. Look... It's hard to help you here if you don't give details. And i already asked you to edit your question... (tf-error: yeah well... and now: reinstall tensorflow and react to error-messages; how can we guess what kind of problem you have; i hope you know how to use anaconda and did not install tf through pip )

Comment: I have edited the question...I have installed tensorflow using pip

Comment: Then think about why to use pip to install tensorflow (which probably fails on windows) when you are using anaconda. Read some introduction to these tools. Use anaconda to install tensorflow! Yeah, it seems to be a requisite for this lib, as heavy as it is!