# How to install watson_developer_cloud in python 3.6

Tags: python, ibm-watson, watson

I need to install watson-developer-cloud for in my python3.6 under windows10. So I tried following steps

```
pip install --upgrade watson-developer-cloud
```

But I got following error

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xyz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "xyz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "xyz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "xyz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "xyz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 487, in _prepare_file
    req_to_install, finder)
  File "xyz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 428, in _check_skip_installed
    req_to_install, upgrade_allowed)
  File "xyz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "xyz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "xyz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "xyz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "xyz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 811, in get_page
    inst = cls(resp.content, resp.url, resp.headers)
  File "xyz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 731, in __init__
    namespaceHTMLElements=False,
TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transport_encoding'
```

how to install watson-developer-cloud?

Comment: if your using anaconda maybe use conda install if available otherwise try to upgrade pip as suggest in the error message... did you read : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watson-developer-cloud ?

Comment: @JamesZ, I have added the text of error messages

Comment: Any suggestion please?

Comment: you are using anaconda so you should try to first update pip from conda : `conda install pip` then install watson-developer-cloud again

Comment: I have updated my pip. Currently I'm using pip version 9.0.3. But still I'm getting error

Comment: did you  it from conda ? also have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46499808/pip-throws-typeerror-parse-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-transport-enco

Comment: Yes, I did it using conda only.

Comment: Any suggestion please?